# Working with Interceptors in OkHttp library

Tags: java, retrofit, okhttp, interceptor

I need to generate a signature authentification with all request parameters:

- Query
- Method
- Body
- Security token

So, I have written a small SignatureInterceptor class:

```
public class SignatureInterceptor implements Interceptor {

    private String token;
    private String signature = "";
    private String method;
    private String query;

    public SignatureInterceptor() {
            this.token = "456456456456";
    }

    @Override
    public com.squareup.okhttp.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request originalRequest = chain.request();
        if (originalRequest.body() == null || originalRequest.header("Content-Encoding") != null) {
            return chain.proceed(originalRequest);
        }

        method = originalRequest.method();
        query = originalRequest.urlString();

        Request authenticatedRequest = originalRequest.newBuilder()
                .method(originalRequest.method(), authenticate(originalRequest.body()))
                .addHeader("signature", signature)
                .build();
        return chain.proceed(authenticatedRequest);
    }

    private RequestBody authenticate(final RequestBody body) {
        return new RequestBody() {
            @Override
            public MediaType contentType() {
                return body.contentType();
            }

            @Override
            public long contentLength() throws IOException {
                return -1;
            }

            @Override
            public void writeTo(BufferedSink sink) throws IOException {
                BufferedSink authSink = Okio.buffer(sink);
                body.writeTo(sink);

                String data = authSink.buffer().readUtf8();
                signature = generateSignature(method, query, data, token);
                authSink.close();
            }
        };
    }
}
```

The problem is, with intercetors, the results are streamed during execution, so I can't get the signature value before it has been processed.

So, is-there a smart way to insert in the header the signature value generated in the writeTo() streamed method ?

**UPDATED** code according to @Jesse answer.

```
private class SignatureInterceptor implements Interceptor {

    @Override
    public com.squareup.okhttp.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request originalRequest = chain.request();
        String data = "";
        if (originalRequest.body() != null) {
            BufferedSink authSink = new Buffer();
            originalRequest.body().writeTo(authSink);
            data = authSink.buffer().readUtf8();
            authSink.close();
        }
        Request authenticatedRequest = originalRequest.newBuilder()
                .addHeader(HEADER_SIGNATURE, buildSignature(data))
                .build();
        return chain.proceed(authenticatedRequest);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please share the complete code.

Comment: I've updated my answer. See ya

Comment: Thank you very much, could you please also answer me - what type is your buildSignature method returning. I'm facing issue with passing signature in the request, I'm trying Base64 encoding, but it not seems to help a lot. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, it's just returning a String, nothing more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to create your own RequestBody class; that's only necessary when you transform the body.

Move the contents of your `writeTo` method into `intercept` so you can compute the signature before calling `proceed`. Use that signature to add a header.